# how can allow this loop to call async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this loop:

```
public static void ForEachValue<T>(Action<T> F)
{
    foreach (var E in GetValues<T>())
    {
        F(E);
    }
}
```

It allows to iterate through enum members and call a method for each.

I would like to allow to take async methods as well and await them, but I can't find the syntax that would work.

Comment: An async method should be returning a `Task` so you need `Func<T, Task>`

Comment: ahh yes; it works; thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async method should be returning a `Task` so you need to use `Func<T, Task>` instead of `Action<T>`. So you could do this and `await` every task:

```
public static async Task ForEachValue<T>(Func<T, Task> F)
{
    foreach (var E in GetValues<T>())
    {
        await F(E);
    }
}
```

Or you could even shorten it to this:

```
public static async Task ForEachValue<T>(Func<T, Task> F)
{
    var tasks = GetValues<T>().Select(F);
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);  
}
```